# what to use: bring or take

Tags: bring-take

To understand the meaning of the usage of bring and take: is it correct to say 'I was picked up from the hospital and was brought home.' and 'My husband picked me up from the hospital and took me home' Thank you in advance!

Comment: Both sound OK to me

Comment: You actually have two different things going on with those sentences at the same time. One is the difference between *brought* and *took*; the other is the difference between passive and active.

Comment: Yes I realise this now. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'I was picked up from the hospital and was brought home.'

this sentence is in the **passive** voice. The agent who did the picking up and bringing home is not specified. Otherwise, we would see "I" (first person subject) become "me" (first person object); "*Someone* picked *me* up and took *me* home."

Note also that in keeping the sentences more parallel, you could have written, "I was picked up... and was taken [took?] home."

> 'My husband picked me up from the hospital and took me home'

The subject clarifies here (*my* **husband**), and the first person [objective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)), **me**, appears. Note that given the nature of expressions, you pretty much have to force repetition in this instance. *My husband picked up and took me home from the hospital* reads awkward to me.

So the difference is semantic, namely, [perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person) or actor. Both sentences are grammatical.

Comment: Thank you so much! So it should me either 'My husband picked me up from the hospital and brought me home' or 'The taxi driver picked me up from the hospital and took me home'.

Comment: Assuming your husband came home with you, but the taxi driver didn't. _Bring_ is the causative of _come_, and _take_ is the causative of _go_; that is, _bring_ means 'cause to come' and _take_ means 'cause to go', so they contrast in the same ways that _come_ and _go_ do. This is not as simple as you may think -- see the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html), especially "May We Come In?" and "Coming and Going".